# Finding angle between the lines containing a particular point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, angle

Suppose we have two non-perpendicular lines of slopes $m_1$ and $m_2$ in the cartesian plane. There are two angles that the lines make with each other , $θ$ and $π-θ$ as shown in below figure.
[image]

We know that angles between line of slopes $m_1$ and $m_2$ is given by :

$$\tan θ= ±\left(\frac{m_1 - m_2}
{1+m_1m_2}\right) $$

The problem was to find that angle between the lines whose angular region contains the point $P(a,b)$ ; which is $\theta$ according to figure.

My teacher said , that $\theta$ is given by :

$$ \tan θ= +\left(\frac{m_1 - m_2}
{1+m_1m_2}\right) $$

He said that it is $m_1-m_2$ in the numerator instead of $m_2-m_1$ because when you traverse from the line of slope $m_1$ to line of slope $m_2$ , then you move in clockwise direction. Hence , we have to take this. In other words , he said that the procedure is always is to take the $+/-$ sign such that the movement corresponding to terms in numerator is clockwise.

However , I am unable to prove that why this procedure works.

Comment: @DS No , it is anti clockwise. A clockwise rotation of acute angle would make it to the fourth quadrant. Also , how does this even explain the above procedure ?

Comment: Ah yes, that was oversight on my part

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your teacher's arguments. Can you add the exact question (which probably had numbers instead of variables)?

Comment: @DS Yes. I'll edit and add it (after some hours )

Comment: @An_Elephant -- 1st ask your teacher if he knows the definition of $\Delta$, if he says no, explain him, starting from situation **1** change something to get to situation **2**, thus $m_1+\Delta{m}=m_2$, or $\Delta{m}=m_2−m_1$ and nothing else. By that you get the sign of your formula correct.<br/>
Now two numeric examples with _extreme_ slopes. i) $m_1=−5$, $m_2=5$, $\displaystyle \tan(θ)=\frac{(5−(−5)}{1+(−5)\cdot 5}=\frac{10}{−24}\approx −0.4167$ and $θ\approx −0,3948$ what is $\lt 0$ so you have to turn line 1 **clockwise** to line 2.

Comment: @An_Elephant -- Example ii) $m_1=-0.2$, $m_2=0.2$, $\displaystyle\tan(θ)=\frac{0.2-(-0.2)}{1+(-0.2)\cdot 0.2}=\frac{0.4}{0.96}\approx 0.4167$ and $θ\approx 0.3948$ what is $\gt 0$ so you have to turn line 1 **counterclockwise** to line 2. In that case the point P(a, b) lies on the oposite side and you have to take the _adjacent angle_ $\pi - θ$ as result. HTH